# fetch data react .map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, fetch-api, use-effect

Why does this code give me: `TypeError: items.map is not a function`?

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])

  const url = 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/1'

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchEmployees() {
      const response = await fetch(url)
      const fetchedEmployees = await response.json(response)
      setItems(fetchedEmployees)
    }
    fetchEmployees()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((element) => (
        <li>{element.name}</li>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: What _is_ `fetchedEmployees`? Also why are you passing `response` to `response.json`?

Comment: Make sure that `await response.json(response)` gives you an array because `.map` can only be used on an array.

Comment: I copied "how fetch from api" because I thought maybe my code is invalid and I didn't change the name of the function

Comment: you need to check response.status or response.ok or response.statusText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass the response inside `response.json()`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchEmployees() {
      const response = await fetch(url)
      const fetchedEmployees = await response.json()
      setItems(fetchedEmployees)
    }
    fetchEmployees()
  }, [])
```

Since your API doesn't return an array, you can't use `map` on `items` . The following should do

```
return (
    <div>
        <li>{items.name}</li>
    </div>
  )
```

If you're trying to fetch an array of objects, you should probably check another endpoint that returns an array of characters like this https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character. You can then map through `items.results` to output the `name` inside your component's JSX.

Comment: A small note that, the `response` from https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character does not immediately return an array. The array of characters seems to actually be in `response.results`

Answer (score 2):

I saw two problems in your code.

Firstly, the API link "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/1" returns **an object**, not an array. You cannot use `map` for object, as `map` is an Array function. Recheck the URL of the API and adjust your code accordingly to match the shape of your value.

Secondly, for your `fetchEmployees()` function, you only need `const fetchedEmployees = await response.json()`

In cases like this, you are encouraged to use "print debugging" - putting `console.log` all over the place to get the idea of what is the internal working. For example, you can put a `console.log` here to see what you are getting (an object) and you should understand why `map` is not working on it

```
async function fetchEmployees() {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const fetchedEmployees = await response.json();
      console.log("fetchedEmployess", fetchedEmployees);
      setItems(fetchedEmployees)
    }
``
```